# How should my Mac application handle a fatal error?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl, fatal-error

I am creating a Cocoa OpenGL game in Xcode, which I wish to at some point distribute on the Mac App store. I'm unsure what to do when my application encounters a fatal error, namely being unable to create a pixel format or OpenGL context. I think I should display some message saying what happened, perhaps giving the user a form to enter a quick comment and have it sent to me (how would I do this?), and then terminate. But what would be the best way to do this?

```
…

NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attribs[] = {
    …
    NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,           // Hardware acceleration
    NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,          // Double buffering
    NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 320,        // *** THIS IS FOR TESTING FAILURE ***
    0
};

// Create pixel format
pixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attribs];
if (!pixelFormat) {
    //////////////////////////////FATAL ERROR//////////////////////////////
}

// Create OpenGL context
openGLContext = [[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:pixelFormat shareContext:nil];
if (!openGLContext) {
    //////////////////////////////FATAL ERROR//////////////////////////////
}

…
```

Notice I've requested a color size of 320 simply to test what will happen in this unlikely case.

I've looked into `NSAlert` but it seems to be more suited for warning messages, even when the style is set to `NSCriticalAlertStyle`. And I think afterwards I should quit with `[NSApp terminate:nil]` but I'm unsure. What should I do in these cases, to be consistent other apps and to conform to the Apple way of doing such a thing?

Note that this only happens on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should ask the user for info. You should probably write state to disk and then offer to send the crash report on next startup. Your data should record what the user's last N actions were, etc. Asking the user for info is irritating to the user, and probably won't give you the real info you need.

Comment: This only happens immeadately upon startup, so recording their actions wouldn't make sense. I think your suggestions are good for a general sense of handling fatal erros, but I was also looking for a specific way to present an error to the user in Cocoa.

Comment: Ok, but I still think you don't need anything interactive. A simple alert should do it. What is insufficient about NSAlert?

Comment: Yea, I guess you're right… When I tried `NSCriticalAlertStyle` and found it gave the exclamation mark yellow triangle warning sign, I thought I was missing something because I was expecting something like a red circle with the horizontal white line for a fatal error. But yea, I think I'll just use the NSAlert and simply say `APPNAME has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue (Error code ERRNO).` Thanks.

Comment: It's better to tell what error exactly happened instead of generic "fatal error" message. If you will display error that "Can not allocate pixel format" or "Can not initialize pixel format" then it will be good for you when user will report this error message to you. You will know what part of code encountered this error and you maybe will be able to provide support for user.

Comment: @MM Yes, user's are much more likely to report english text (that they can remember) vs a strange number (that they probably will forget)

Comment: I agree, I've changed my message to the following: `APPNAME has encountered a fatal error. \n [Could not create pixel format] \n If the problem persists, please contact us at AppNameSupport@example.com.`

Comment: If you have a question about whether a UI element is appropriate or not, you should consult the [Mac Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html), that's what they're for.